# Share Kit Twitter log in screen not correct in Landscape Mode

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, sharekit

I am trying to test ShareKit in Landscape mode. Twitter is giving trouble. The login interface(OAuth) comes in Portrait mode and the Keypad comes in Landscape.

And the log in window only occupies 1/4th of the screen and it comes in the portrait mode.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.